# Strip newrelic rum.js scripts for certain routes in rails

Tags: html, http, attachment, instrumentation, newrelic

I am using newrelic ruby agent and it is inserting some js code to each hmtl response from my app, for example in head: var NREUMQ=[];NREUMQ.push(["mark","firstbyte",new Date().getTime()]);

Problem is, that we allow users to host content, and sometimes they host html files. Then newrelic is inserting these lines to their html when they click on download...

Example html downloaded through site with newrelic additions. Any advice how to strip the newrelic stuff only for certain routes or any other methods that we can use for specific code paths only?

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: nginx/1.1.8
Date: Thu, 26 Apr 2012 19:25:54 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 1176
Connection: keep-alive
Vary: Accept-Encoding
X-Powered-By: Phusion Passenger (mod_rails/mod_rack) 3.0.11
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
X-Runtime: 0.340155
Progma: cache
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="404.html"
Expires: 0
Cache-Control: private
Set-Cookie: ;)
Status: 200

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head><script>var NREUMQ=[];NREUMQ.push(["mark","firstbyte",new Date().getTime()]);</script>
  <title>The page you were looking for doesn't exist (404)</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body { background-color: #fff; color: #666; text-align: center; font-family: arial, sans-serif; }
    div.dialog {
      width: 25em;
      padding: 0 4em;
      margin: 4em auto 0 auto;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-right-color: #999;
      border-bottom-color: #999;
    }
    h1 { font-size: 100%; color: #f00; line-height: 1.5em; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- This file lives in public/404.html -->
  <div class="dialog">
    <h1>The page you were looking for doesn't exist.</h1>
    <p>You may have mistyped the address or the page may have moved.</p>
  </div>
<script>(function(){var d=document;var e=d.createElement("script");e.async=true;e.src="https://d1ros97qkrwjf5.cloudfront.net/30/eum/rum.js";var s=d.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(e,s);})();NREUMQ.push(["nrf2","beacon-1.newrelic.com","9dfe439095",309309,"blablabla==",0,336,new Date().getTime()])</script></body>
</html>
```

I have tried using:
    include NewRelic::Agent::Instrumentation::ControllerInstrumentation
    newrelic_ignore :only => "download"
In my controller, but it does not seem to have any effect.

When I restart my passenger, the code is not appended to any page for a short while, after that, it is to all pages, even those that have newrelic_ignore

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can turn off auto-instrumentation for New Relic RUM--that's what's inserting the JS automatically in your pages. There's a setting in `newrelic.yml` that turns auto-RUM on and off. See the [documentation for RUM in Ruby](https://newrelic.com/docs/ruby/real-user-monitoring-in-ruby) for details.

After you've done that, you can manually add back instrumentation for the actions you want to measure end user page load time for. How to do so is also described in the docs--you call Ruby agent API methods to insert a header and footer in your pages.

Comment: after talking to New Relic Customer Support, this can only be accomplished globally, and then added back individually.

Comment: It looks like you can blacklist for a controller using [newrelic_ignore_enduser](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/agents/ruby-agent/installation-configuration/ignoring-specific-transactions#page-load-timing-rum)